# .stop() function doesn't work with sprites

Tags: python, oop, arcade

I was writing a simple ping pong game as an introduction to arcade and in the loop on line 51. It is supposed to stop the sprites moving but it just isn't happening. I tried to remove the `self.`, but got an error, tried replacing `self.` with `arcade.`, but still getting an error.

```
import arcade

screen_width = 900
screen_height = 800
screen_title = 'Pingpong'

class MainGame(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self, width, height, title):
        super().__init__(width, height, title)
        self.ball = ball('ball.png', 0.4)
        self.bar = bar('barman.png', 0.5)
        self.live = 3
        self.score = 0

    def setup(self):
        self.ball.center_x = 450
        self.ball.center_y = 400
        self.ball.stepx = 15
        self.ball.stepy = 15

        self.bar.center_x = 400
        self.bar.center_y = 70
        self.bar.stepx = 0

    def on_draw(self):
        arcade.start_render()
        self.ball.draw()
        self.bar.draw()
        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.DARK_GRAY)
        life = f'Жизней: {self.live}'
        scrore = f'Счёт: {self.score}'
        arcade.draw_text(life, 750, 740, arcade.color.BLACK, 20)
        arcade.draw_text(scrore, 10, 740, arcade.color.BLACK, 20)
        if self.live == 0:
            arcade.draw_text('Вы лох', 400, 400, arcade.color.RED_DEVIL, 60)
        arcade.finish_render()

    def update(self, delta_time: float):
        self.ball.update()
        self.bar.update()
        colliding = arcade.check_for_collision(self.ball, self.bar)
        if colliding:
            self.ball.bottom = self.example.top
            self.ball.stepy = -self.ball.stepy
            self.score += 1

        if self.ball.bottom < 0:
            self.live -= 1
            self.ball.center_x = 450
            self.ball.center_y = 400

        if self.live == 0:
            ball.stop()
            bar.stop()

    def on_key_press(self, key, modifiers):
        if key == arcade.key.A:
            self.bar.stepx = -15
        if key == arcade.key.D:
            self.bar.stepx = 15

    def on_key_release(self, key, modifiers):
        if key == arcade.key.A or key == arcade.key.D:
            self.bar.stepx = 0

class ball(arcade.Sprite):
    def update(self):
        self.center_x += self.stepx
        self.center_y += self.stepy

        if self.bottom < 0 or self.top > screen_height:
            self.stepy = -self.stepy
        if self.left < 0 or self.right > screen_width:
            self.stepx = -self.stepx

class bar(arcade.Sprite):
    def update(self):
        self.center_x += self.stepx
        if self.left < 0 or self.right > screen_width:
            self.stepx = 0



game = MainGame(screen_width, screen_height, screen_title)
game.setup()
arcade.run()
```

I tried removing the `self.` and got an error, tried replacing the `self.` with an arcade, got an error too. The loop works too it seems

Answer (score 0):

Calling `stop` doesn't make sense in your code because at the same time you're updating your sprites coordinates. You need to update `ball` and `bar` only wnen `live` is above `0`:

```
import arcade

screen_width = 900
screen_height = 800
screen_title = 'Pingpong'


class MainGame(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self, width, height, title):
        super().__init__(width, height, title)
        self.ball = ball('ball.png', 0.4)
        self.bar = bar('barman.png', 0.5)
        self.live = 3
        self.score = 0

    def setup(self):
        self.ball.center_x = 450
        self.ball.center_y = 400
        self.ball.stepx = 15
        self.ball.stepy = 15

        self.bar.center_x = 400
        self.bar.center_y = 70
        self.bar.stepx = 0

    def on_draw(self):
        arcade.start_render()
        self.ball.draw()
        self.bar.draw()
        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.DARK_GRAY)
        life = f'Жизней: {self.live}'
        score = f'Счёт: {self.score}'
        arcade.draw_text(life, 750, 740, arcade.color.BLACK, 20)
        arcade.draw_text(score, 10, 740, arcade.color.BLACK, 20)
        if self.live == 0:
            arcade.draw_text('Вы лох', 400, 400, arcade.color.RED_DEVIL, 60)
        arcade.finish_render()

    def update(self, delta_time: float):
        if self.live > 0:
            self.ball.update()
            self.bar.update()
            colliding = arcade.check_for_collision(self.ball, self.bar)
            if colliding:
                self.ball.bottom = self.bar.top
                self.ball.stepy = -self.ball.stepy
                self.score += 1

            if self.ball.bottom < 0:
                self.live -= 1
                self.ball.center_x = 450
                self.ball.center_y = 400

    def on_key_press(self, key, modifiers):
        if key == arcade.key.A:
            self.bar.stepx = -15
        if key == arcade.key.D:
            self.bar.stepx = 15

    def on_key_release(self, key, modifiers):
        if key == arcade.key.A or key == arcade.key.D:
            self.bar.stepx = 0


class ball(arcade.Sprite):
    def update(self):
        self.center_x += self.stepx
        self.center_y += self.stepy

        if self.bottom < 0 or self.top > screen_height:
            self.stepy = -self.stepy
        if self.left < 0 or self.right > screen_width:
            self.stepx = -self.stepx


class bar(arcade.Sprite):
    def update(self):
        self.center_x += self.stepx
        if self.left < 0 or self.right > screen_width:
            self.stepx = 0


game = MainGame(screen_width, screen_height, screen_title)
game.setup()
arcade.run()
```

Output:

[image]